# NSLocalization info.Plist not found

Tags: xcode, info.plist, nslocalizedstring

I localized my info.Plist to support other languages and get info.Plist not found when trying to run the app. I also tried to create infoPlist.string file as recommended in other post, but this was unsucessful as well, 
i.e.
`info.plist` specifically for

```
"Privacy-Calendars Usage Description" = "はカレンダーを使用してリマインダーを追加したいと考えています。";
```

But it is not working.

I created an `infoPlist.strings` `'strings'` file localized it added the above to (Japanese) strings file but did not work. Any suggestions?

So needless to say neither one of the examples i have tried succedded to solve my issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the plist and select **Show Raw Keys / Values** you'll see the correct keys to use in your `infoPlist.strings` file

The correct key for your example is `NSCalendarsUsageDescription` (rather than `Privacy-Calendars Usage Description`)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I tried what you have mentioned and used the rawvalues in my InfoPlist.strings file speciffically InfoPlist.strings(Japanese) file but the translation is still not working. I also used the same keys in my Localizable.strings file with no results. Odd I think it's not working. Any thoughts ?